# HM Stack, can python free up the memory?

Tags: python, arguments

Got a task to create a function `list_updater` that should take on not defined number of arguments and if specified argument so-called `collection[]` is given as a parameter as well, add it up before any other parameter and return the list.

I have a code that works perfectly if one iteration is done, however, because *argv is the memory pointer when it is called a second time, it adds up parameters from the previous call.

I am searching for a way to either free up the memory from *argv or a alternative to it.

example on how program should behave:

> list_updater(9, 10, 25, collection=[7]) == [7, 9, 10, 25]

My code:

```
def list_updater(*argv, collection = []):
    if collection == None:
        collection = []
    for i in argv:
        collection.append(i)
    return collection
```

With my code:

```
print(list_updater(1,2,3))
print(list_updater('test','test'))
```

Prints:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,'test','test']
```

Should print:

```
[1,2,3]
['test','test']
```

Thanks!